# IntelliJ Deploy to GAE not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, intellij-idea

I'd like to deploy a GWT-App to GAE in IntelliJ but I can't figure out what the problem is. I always get the following error:

> Error running Google App Engine Deployment: Deployment is not selected

But in the Run configuration there is nothing in the dropdown to select:
[image]

I can also not configure the GAE account in the facet view like described in [the help section of IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/google-app-engine-facet-page.html):
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

1. First, select "Edit Configurations", as seen here:

   [image: Edit Configurations]
2. Then, edit the configuration as follows:

   [image: edit step as picture]

Answer (score -1):

I went to the "artifacts" section under "project settings" and added the project library under "available elements".

I was able to select a deployment after that.